# What is the difference between @CamelSpringTest and @CamelSpringBootTest?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel

I am just starting a projects that combines Spring Boot and Apache Camel (what seems a very nice combination).

In regards of testing with JUnit 5 Google brings up [this page](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/others/test-spring-junit5.html). It suggests to use `@CamelSpringTest` if you want to have both the annotations from Spring and Camel (what i want).

At the and of the page there are suggestion for JUnit 4 Test migration that suggests:

> Usage of @RunWith(CamelSpringRunner.class) should be replaced with
> @CamelSpringTest
> ...
> Usage of @RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class) should be replaced with
> @CamelSpringBootTest

My question is for new project/ tests: What is the difference of both in regards of usage.
There is of course difference in code but i don't have a clue for what reason:

CamelSpringTest:

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE })
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@BootstrapWith(CamelTestContextBootstrapper.class)
@TestExecutionListeners(
                        value = {
                                CamelSpringTestContextLoaderTestExecutionListener.class,
                                StopWatchTestExecutionListener.class
                        },
                        mergeMode = TestExecutionListeners.MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)
public @interface CamelSpringTest {

}
```

CamelSpringBootTest

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE })
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@TestExecutionListeners(
                        value = {
                                CamelSpringTestContextLoaderTestExecutionListener.class,
                                CamelSpringBootExecutionListener.class,
                                StopWatchTestExecutionListener.class
                        },
                        mergeMode = TestExecutionListeners.MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)
public @interface CamelSpringBootTest {

}
```

Comment: I would suggest you post this question to camel mailing list and may be come back later to share the knowledge

Comment: my last attempts there yielded most often the answer: "please put this question in stackoverflow".

Answer (score 6):

The difference is quite simple: is the test running in a SpringBoot project or not?

Camel can be used in a pure Spring project (without Boot). In such a project you can either extend `CamelSpringTestSupport` to write Tests or you can use `@CamelSpringTest` annotation. The tests are then started and initialized for this environment.

When you use [Camel in a SpringBoot project](https://camel.apache.org/camel-spring-boot/latest/spring-boot.html), Camel can leverage this environment with auto-configuration etc. Therefore you have to use another annotation,  `@CamelSpringBootTest`, to write tests. See [here for an example](https://camel.apache.org/camel-spring-boot/latest/spring-boot.html#_testing_the_junit_5_way).

So the two annotations are just "activators" for two different Camel test facilities for different project types. And these are just the Spring facilities. See this page for [even more Camel test facilities](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/testing.html).

This is also the source of many confusions around Camel testing. There are so much test variations, Spring, SpringBoot, JUnit 4, JUnit 5 etc. it is really hard to know what annotations are needed for what combinations of testing setup.